# How to integrate our apps code in to other app with out sharing the source code in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, frameworks

I have developed an iPad pdf reader application,i need to integrate this app with other's app with out giving them the source code.I hope packaging my entire application as frame work and providing them with API will do the trick(not sure).So can any one please show me a way to create frame works in iOS or help me out if there is a better approach for this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a static library. A google search should do the trick, but here's a link to get you started:
[Creating Static Libraries For iOS](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

Comment: [Another reference](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) for static libs in Xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

One other way to integrate an app with other apps is using a custom URL scheme. End users install your app normally and other apps can use it.

Let's say you create a scheme named `pdfreader` for your app. Any other app (of web app) using an URL like `pdfreader://file.pdf?a=1&b=2` will launch your app with the passed parameters.

Apps like [Aurigma Up](http://www.aurigma.com/iphone/) use this kind of scheme.

More explanations on how to do it [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Also look at other shared inter-app communications schemes [here](http://handleopenurl.com/).